# is this correct way to use try catch block

Tags: c#, try-catch, except

I wanted to throw an exception if something went wrong in the method resubmit()

```
 var manager = new ApprovalsDashboardManager();        
    try
    {
        manager.Resubmit(requestId, userId);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {

        throw new ApplicationException("Resubmit Request Failed, Please resubmit in a while", e.InnerException);
    }
```

Is his correct way of using try catch block and I wanted to know how to error handle methods which are in other project being called in my current project.

Comment: If you are throwing a ApplicationException you should only catch ApplicationExceptions. This will stop you from ignoring other errors that could occur. Catching all exceptions is generally a bad practice. Exception handling is also so that you can deal with the problem. Throwing another exception is basically pointless. You should be managing the error, maybe by displaying a message box or something.

Comment: why do you want to catch an exception if all you're going to do is throw another exception? is there actually any value in catching the exception at that point in the first place?

Comment: If you are wrapping an exception with another exception (I'm not judging if it is good or bad per se in the given context), the second parameter of the exception constructor should be `e` instead of `e.InnerException` perhaps.

Answer (score 1):

Syntactically, yes, this is the correct way to use a try-catch block. However, if you have access to the code, I would suggest modifying the ApprovalsDashboardManager.Resubmit() method so that it throws your custom ApplicationException when something goes wrong. It's a little redundant to catch an exception just to throw another exception.

EDIT: However, it is not "bad practice" to do this. This use-case is included in the MSDN page for try-catch. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yd65esw.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If your "ReSubmit" function is throwing the exception, you don't need to throw it again. It is acceptable to handle the exception simply by providing some information to the user about what happened.

So you would do this somewhere in the catch. You did right by adding some more information into the exception's *Message*, this is good practice.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with wrapping exceptions, as you have done, is that it tends to conceal the true source of the error, because the stack trace reflects the point where the exception was thrown. This is mitigated somewhat because you've included the original exception as the `InnerException`.

This CAN be a legitimate thing to do, if you are hiding implementation details and don't want to expose those details to users via an exception. The user of an exception though, most often, is a developer and the more accurate and detailed information you can give them the better.

I'm also wary of catching all exceptions. What happens if you get an OutOfMemoryException, for example? Do you really want to ignore that? If you don't know what to do about running out of memory, then it might be better to let that exception bubble up to the next level where some other code might know what to do about it.